# Extract value from a list formatted like a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, list, rss, feedparser

I have a function that returns an image URL from an RSS feed (I'm using feedparser). The problem is that it returns a strange formatted list.

My feed has a key called `media_content`. The code used to access it is

```
import feedparser
NewsFeed = feedparser.parse("https://thegroovecartel.com/feed/")
entry = NewsFeed.entries[0]
post_image = entry.media_content
```

Now, for some reason post_image is a list of 1 element formattes as:

```
[{'url': 'https://thegroovecartel.com/i1.wp.com/thegroovecartel.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/KAYYA.jpg?fit=300%2C237&ssl=1', 'medium': 'image'}]
```

Now, I can't understand how to access the actual URL field to have `https://thegroovecartel.com/i1.wp.com/thegroovecartel.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/KAYYA.jpg?fit=300%2C237&ssl=1` as a string into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
post_image = [{'url': 'https://thegroovecartel.com/i1.wp.com/thegroovecartel.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/KAYYA.jpg?fit=300%2C237&ssl=1', 'medium': 'image'}]
print(post_image[0]['url'])
```

> Result

```
https://thegroovecartel.com/i1.wp.com/thegroovecartel.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/KAYYA.jpg?fit=300%2C237&ssl=1
```

You've got to treat `post_image` as a list, assessing its first element (i.e. element with index 0), gives you the dictionary that contains your image's attribute